# how to resolve this error in mysql while importing a large data file?

Tags: mysql, excel

14:20:28 Restoring E:\downloads\covid_sql_project\CovidDeathsss.xlsx
Running: mysql.exe --defaults-file="C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp6zk3nxgc.cnf"  --protocol=tcp --host=localhost --user=root --port=3306 --default-character-set=utf8 --comments --database=prj1dataexploration  < "E:\downloads\covid_sql_project\CovidDeathsss.xlsx"
ERROR at line 1: ASCII '\0' appeared in the statement, but this is not allowed unless option --binary-mode is enabled and mysql is run in non-interactive mode. Set --binary-mode to 1 if ASCII '\0' is expected. Query: 'PK
'.

Operation failed with exitcode 1
14:20:34 Import of E:\downloads\covid_sql_project\CovidDeathsss.xlsx has finished with 1 errors

Comment: See the accepted answer to the duplicate question. Mysql command line client cannot directly import an excel file.